# How do I create a .desktop file for a .jar file?

Tags: launcher, minecraft, .desktop

My problem is, that I do want to create a .desktop file for Technic Launcher, which is an alternative launcher for Minecraft. It comes in the form of a .jar file and I want to create a menu entry for it. How would I write such a .desktop file?

My attempt was the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Technic Launcher
Comment=Minecraft Launcher for Technic Pack, Tekkit, Hack/Mine and Yogbox
Exec=/home/benjamin/Applications/Minecraft/TechnicLauchner/technic-launcher-latest.jar
Icon=/home/benjamin/Applications/Minecraft/TechnicLauchner/icon.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;ActionGame;AdventureGame;RolePlaying;
```

This didn't work, hence my question. What did I do wrong? Is it even possible to point to a .jar file?

Answer (score 18):

You can make it manualy, or using [Alacarte[image: Install]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/). Here's the way:

## 1: [Install Alacarte](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/)

It will install some Gnome dependencies. Nothing to worry about.

## 2: Create a new entry

In the command entry, click browse and select your .jar file.

- You may need to add `/usr/bin/java -jar`  to the start of the Command, so that it looks like `/usr/bin/java -jar /home/angel/minecraft.jar`.

[image]

## 3: Make the file executable

Go where you have your .jar file. Right click, properties, permissions, check the 'Allow run as a program' option.

## 4: Look for it in the Dash

There you should have it. Just click and enjoy!

[image]

## Extra: [Here's](http://dharmainitiative2010.deviantart.com/art/Minecraft-Icon-187010413) the icon

Comment: Personally, I prefer menulibre. It was added with the last App showdown and offers a better experience than alacarte, imo: https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1173/

Comment: @Glutanimate I've never used MenuLibre before. And I tried to use it in the answer. But due to a bug in Quantal I can't install it, so I chose Alacarte.

Comment: I always thought it was very easy to create `.desktop` files, because KDE has this functionality built-in.

Comment: **Very Important**: `java` needs to be in the `PATH` to execute. If you exported your `PATH` in `.bashrc`, move it to `.profile` so the desktop environment has the correct `PATH` when you run the application.

Comment: Any idea why when I open my banking application through the `.desktop` icon it can't connect to the internet? When I run the exact same `java -jar ...` command in the terminal it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 14):

**.jar** files are not executable, so you have to open them with something (`java`):

```
Exec=java -jar /home/benjamin/Applications/Minecraft/TechnicLauchner/technic-launcher-latest.jar
```

Anyway, I wouldn't recommend creating those files manually from scratch.

Answer (score 6):

You just messed up a part of the Desktop file. This is what it should look like (sorry for the thread resurrection):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Technic Launcher
Comment=Minecraft Launcher for Technic Pack, Tekkit, Hack/Mine and Yogbox
Exec=java -jar /home/benjamin/Applications/Minecraft/TechnicLauchner/technic-launcher-latest.jar
Icon=/home/benjamin/Applications/Minecraft/TechnicLauchner/icon.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Game;ActionGame;AdventureGame;RolePlaying;
```

Then just type

```
sudo chmod +x "/home/(username)/Desktop/Technic Launcher.desktop"
```

Answer (score 2):

On a Xubuntu I just gave the the absolute path of the jar file and mad it executable using the `chmod +x` on jar file.

On the permissions tab just clicked over run file as an program.

---

Or you may want to associate the .jar extension with the java application.

With Xubuntu you can do this via Configuration manager Dialog and choosing the 
**System -> MIME Editor** by editing the entry at `application/java-x-archive` to the preferred Java Virtual Machine.